# How to find a function using domain and range in math?

Tags: functions

I want to find a function, given domain and range.
Example:

```
Domain Range
2      6
4      8
6      20
7      24
```

> This is just an example. I want to know the method of creating functions regardless of the values in `Domain` and `Range`

Then how can I find a function using `Domain` and `Range`?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table can be used to define the function and it is a completely correct definition.

If you are looking for a closed form, we can use for example [**polynomial interpolation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Refer also to the following

- **[Explanation of Lagrange Interpolating Polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/523907/505767)**

Answer (score -2):

你能通过你已知的函数，例如指数函数，对数函数，幂函数这些你很熟悉的函数进行配凑，因为你知道它的性质，在哪个区间增长或减少，然后合理添加常数进行配凑。我建议你先画出x -y坐标系,标记出domain and range 所在的矩形区域，再考虑用哪一个函数将它放入这个区域，使得这个函数在矩形区域内并且可以取到最大最小值。these  are  answered by chinese you are suggested to use google  translator.

> *Translated From `Google Translator`:*
>   You can use a function you
>   know, such as an exponential function, a logarithmic function, a power
>   function, a function that you are familiar with, because you know its
>   nature, in which interval it grows or decreases, and then add a
>   constant to match . I suggest that you first draw the x-y coordinate
>   system, mark the rectangular area where the domain and range are
>   located, and then consider which function to put it into this area, so
>   that this function is in the rectangular area and can get the maximum
>   and minimum